# C++ std::system 'system' not a Member of std

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, include, std

I receive an error compiling a C++ program in which of the lines makes a call from "std::system(SomeString)". This program compiled 3 years ago, but when compiling it today, I receive an error that states ‘system’ is not a member of ‘std’. Is there something that I must import to use std::system, has it been abandoned, or has it moved to another header file.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`std::system` is (and always has been) in `<cstdlib>`.

It is not defined by the C++ standard whether standard headers include each other, and if so which ones. So it's possible that 3 years ago, on a different compiler or a different version of the same compiler, your code worked by accident, because one of the headers you include just so happened to include `<cstdlib>`. On the compiler/version you're using now, it doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

Do you have this?:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have `#include <cstdlib>` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried. 
It work both ways in vs2008 -- "std::system()" or "system()".
And you want to include either stdlib.h or cstdlib

Comment: What new information you answer give in compare with accepted one?